# unexpected identifier in javascript, but I have declared the variable

Tags: javascript, uncaught-exception

I've looked at this file for an hour and have tried a ton of permutations.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var unreadMessages = document.getElementsByClassName("unreadMessage");

var previousEntries;

chrome.storage.sync.get(null, {
    var previousEntries;
    previousEntries = (data["item"]);
});

console.log(previousEntries);


});
```

Why does previousEntries throw an "Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected identifier"? 
This seems to be the most straightforward task. Is it a } () or , issue?

Comment: where is that `data` in `data["item"]` coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var unreadMessages = document.getElementsByClassName("unreadMessage");

  var previousEntries;

  //                            vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
  chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(data){
    // var previousEntries;              And if you want to access this variable outside,
    previousEntries = data["item"];   // don't redefine it here (no "var" keyword).
    logValue();                       // Now that the variable is set, you can use it
  });

  // console.log(previousEntries);    // Undefined, because it is not set yet.

  function logValue(){
    console.log(previousEntries);     // Now it should work (called from get's callback).
  }

});
```

The reason the variable is not set yet is that `chrome.storage.sync.get` is, just like Ajax or a `setTimeout`, **asynchronous**. Imagine doing this:

```js
var myVar;

setTimeout(function(){
   myVar = 'Hello world!';
   console.log(myVar);     // logs "Hello world!" to the console
}, 100);

alert(myVar);              // alerts undefined
```

Comment: thanks @blex! i thought .log was always accessible. in fact, it seems it often is by default. any idea why it wouldn't work without being "set"?

Comment: @Alan `chrome.storage.sync.get` is asynchronous, meaning that any code below it will be executed **before** it gets the value. That's why they allow you to have a callback function, that is executed when you get the value. From there, you can execute the rest of your code (`console.log()` or other stuff that need that variable). Think of it like a `setTimeout`: http://jsfiddle.net/fdxgnyyj/